# django dictionary data into html table

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, dictionary

I have following `dictionary` output data of python in browser

```
{'pid': 0, 'name': 'System Process'}
{'pid': 41, 'name': 'System123'}
{'pid': 110, 'name': 'svchost.exe'}
{'pid': 280, 'name': 'smss.exe'}
{'pid': 336, 'name': 'WSE.exe'}
{'pid': 424, 'name': 'csrss.exe'}
```

but want to create a **html / bootstrap** `table` in my `template` such that the output `table` will look similar to:

```
PID   NAME

0     System Idle Process
41    System123
110   svchost.exe
280   smss.exe
336   WSE.exe
..    ..
..    ...
```

**exactly like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIL1.jpg)**

my **template** code:

```
<body>
        {% for obj in mydict_key %}
        <table >
            {{ obj }}
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Do you get PID printed in browser when doing `{{ obj.pid }}` ?

Comment: Is that a list of dictionaries or only some dictionaries?

Comment: @RajaSimon nop just the values of `pid`

Comment: @doru list of dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

Not completely sure about the template syntax, but it would be something like this:

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>PID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    {% for obj in mydict_key %} 
      <tr>
        <td>{{ obj.pid }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean in terms of style?

Comment: Since I answered your question about outputting data, feel free to mark my answer correct (with the checkmark icon) to help future users. If you have Bootstrap properly set up on your site, it should automatically apply styles to all tables. See more information here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of dicts:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'pid': 0, 'name': 'System Process'},
    {'pid': 41, 'name': 'System123'},
    {'pid': 110, 'name': 'svchost.exe'},
    {'pid': 280, 'name': 'smss.exe'},
    {'pid': 336, 'name': 'WSE.exe'},
    {'pid': 424, 'name': 'csrss.exe'} 
]
```

the in the template you can do:

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>PID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    {% for dict in list_of_dicts %} 
       <tr>
          {% for value in dict.values %}       
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, your answer works for me. Thanks!